# Processing a BibTeX database based on entry type

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, resume

Consider a BibTeX database (i.e. a `.bib` file), in which there are over 100 entries. Entry types are journal publications, conference publications, etc., all of which are published by some specific author "A".

Now, assume that "A" wants to create his C.V. based on this `.bib` file. The C.V. must look like this:

```
Name:...
Affiliation: ...
Address: ...
.
.
.
Journal Publications:
----------------------
[1] ...
[2] ...
...
Conference Publications:
----------------------
[1] ...
[2] ...
...
```

Is there a way to process the `.bib` file, and generate an output which displays all entries sorted as shown above?

Comment: Would A consider switching to `biblatex` instead of `bibtex`?

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for the comment. "A" is a professor in my university, who asked me this question. If switching to `biblatex` can be done fairly automatically (i.e. he does not have to write the BST file from scratch), I think he's willing to do so.

Comment: Your terminology is a bit confusing. A `.bst` file is a bibliography style file, whereas `.bib` files are the database file that contain entries -- some of which you may want to reference in any given job. Did you mean to refer to `.bib` files?

Comment: @Mico: You're right. Thanks. I corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `biblatex` you can reuse the `.bib` file. You need to use the `biblatex` package and process the file with `biber` and not `bibtex`. Without any modifications you can get pretty close to what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{abc,
  author = {A Author},
  title = {the article title},
  journal = {the journal},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1--2},
  number = {1},
  month = {1},
  doi = {1234/5678}
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{def,
  author = {A Author},
  title = {the proceeding title},
  journal = {the conference},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {11--12},
  number = {1},
  month = {1},
  doi = {5678/1234}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \subsection*{Journal Publications:}
    \printbibliography[type=article,]

    \subsection*{Conference Publications:}
    \printbibliography[type=inproceedings]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Resetting the numbering, reverse numbering, bold face author and other modifications can also be done (and have been answered here before).

Comment: I apologize, but I cannot figure out how to crop the image.