# Dummy package for .bib files

Tags: bibtex

When answering this question about [CV reference lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57592/processing-a-bibtex-database-based-on-entry-type) I thought it would be helpful if there was a "dummy" `bib` file that I could include. Is there a package like `lipsum` or `blindtext` for `bib` files?

Comment: Based on David's answer I referenced `xampl.bib` now in my `mwe` package manual. There all available keys are also listed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think any BibTeX installation will have this one available

```
 texmf-dist/bibtex/base/xampl.bib
```

That is (in texlive at least) in the default path so you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\nocite*

\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

or cite a specific entry such as

```
@ARTICLE{article-minimal,
   author = {L[eslie] A. Aamport},
   title = {The Gnats and Gnus Document Preparation System},
   journal = {\mbox{G-Animal's} Journal},
   year = 1986,
}
```

Comment: I found it (and a bunch of other bib files), but they were based in texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/ for my TeXLive 2011.

Comment: yes that's where they were in mine but texlive's texmf.cnf puts those directories in the bibtex path so if you latex/bibtex the latex file as posted, then bibtex should find the .bib file. % BibTeX bibliographies and style files.  bibtex8 also uses these.
BIBINPUTS = .;$TEXMF/bibtex/bib//
BSTINPUTS = .;$TEXMF/bibtex/{bst,csf}//

Comment: Good answer. I mentioned it in `mwe` manual now, in case if people need it for MWEs. https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/mwe/commits/0808d265d2b2

Answer (score 18):

Users of [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) may add

```
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
```

to their preamble and thereby make available a sample bibliography with about 70 entries. The contents of this file can be viewed [here](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib).

**Note:** This `.bib` file uses `biblatex`-specific field types like `journaltitle` and is therefore not suitable for users of traditional BibTeX/`.bst` files.