# get emacs to automatically use biber instead of bibtex

Tags: biblatex, emacs, auctex, biber

I was reading the question titled [Customizing emacs to use biblatex-biber instead of bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3904/customising-emacs-to-use-biblatex-biber-instead-of-bibtex).  In that question, user @PLK mentions that as of auctex 11.87, auctex should automatically check if you are using biblatex and if so, switch to using biber.  I have auctex 11.87 installed and running, but I am not getting this automatic switching behavior.

Say I have two files (borrowed from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57592/processing-a-bibtex-database-based-on-entry-type)).

test.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \subsection*{Journal Publications:}
    \printbibliography[type=article]

    \subsection*{Conference Publications:}
    \printbibliography[type=inproceedings]

\end{document}
```

and test.bib

```
@ARTICLE{abc,
  author = {A Author},
  title = {the article title},
  journal = {the journal},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1--2},
  number = {1},
  month = {1},
  doi = {1234/5678}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{def,
  author = {A Author},
  title = {the proceeding title},
  journal = {the conference},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {11--12},
  number = {1},
  month = {1},
  doi = {5678/1234}
}
```

If I run the following commands:

```
pdflatex test.tex
biber test
pdflatex test.tex
```

I end up with a properly processed document.  In emacs, when I press `C-c C-c` and select the `BibTeX` command, emacs runs `bibtex test` instead of `biber test`.  I am then greeted with errors about no `\citation` `\bibdata` or `\bibstyle` commands.  My `bibtex-dialect` variable is automatically getting set to `biblatex`, `LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber` is set to `t`, `TeX-command-Biber` is set to `Biber`, but for some reason `TeX-command-BibTex` variable is still set to BibTeX.  Should this automatically get changed to `Biber`?  Do I have to set it using a local variable?  Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

According to [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Selecting-a-Command.html) in the AUCTeX 11.87 manual:

> In case you use biblatex in a document, AUCTeX switches from BibTeX to Biber for bibliography processing.

So I feel like this automatic switch should already be happening.

Comment: AUCTeX 11.88 will be able to automatically decide whether using `biber` or `bibtex` looking at `biblatex` load options.

Comment: Do you have the lines `(setq TeX-auto-save t) (setq TeX-parse-self t) (setq-default TeX-master nil)` in your `.emacs`?

Comment: I have the first two, but not the `TeX-master` line.  Adding it makes no difference to the behavior.  I just realized that I had a small mistake in my `.emacs`.  Fixing that, I now see that AUCTeX 11.87 has added a `Biber` command to the `TeX-command-list`. Using `C-c C-c` and choosing `Biber` instead of `BibTeX` will allow the document to be correctly processed.  I still feel like either the 11.87 documentation is slightly misleading, or I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, the `TeX-master-file` isn't really important in this case, the only fundamental option is `TeX-parse-self`, which enables parsing.  When parsing is activated, AUCTeX 11.87 will prompt for `Biber` or `BibTex` depending on the value of `LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber`, but won't be able to automatically decide which backend is to be used, you have always to adapt the value of `LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber`.  As I already said, next AUCTeX version will have the ability to choose the right backend.

Comment: Excellent thanks for your help!  It sounds like I was just reading a bit too much into the documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AUCTeX uses `bibtex` as default bibliography processor.  If one activates parsing of LaTeX documents setting the variable `TeX-parse-self` to `t`, in source files with an explicit `\usepackage{biblatex}` line AUCTeX prompts for `biber` or `bibtex` processor depending on the value of the variable `LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber`, which defaults to `t`.  But until version 11.87, AUCTeX isn't able to *automatically* choose the bibliography processor, which is set in a LaTeX document with the `backend` load option of the `biblatex` package.

Starting from version 11.88, to be released in the next weeks or few months, AUCTeX will look at `biblatex` load options to automatically choose between `biber` and `bibtex`.  In this version, the variable `LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber` will be removed since it will be no more needed.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if `\usepackage{biblatex}` is written in different lines as, e.g.,

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=none
             ]
              {biblatex}
```

AUCTeX will not notice it and leaves `LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber` false.