# biblatex-chicago does not run biber automatically in Emacs

Tags: auctex, biblatex-chicago, reftex

I'm using AUCTeX (version 11.90.2)+RefTeX on Emacs (version 24.5.2).
While I'm using the `biblatex` package, if I do <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>, it would suggest `biber` as default.

However, if I use the package `biblatex-chicago` instead, it would suggest that the default option is `bibtex` instead, even when I have the option `backend=biber`.

In this situation, I check that the value of the variable `LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber` is `t`, but it is mentioned in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129237/37198) that the variable `LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber` would be removed since AUCTeX version 11.88 because it will be no more needed.

So how do I set `biblatex-chicago` to behave the same way as `biblatex`? Many thanks!

Comment: Does it help if you set `LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber` as a file local variable?  In your .tex file, try `M-x add-file-local-variable RET LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber RET t RET`?

Comment: @ArashEsbati, it helps! but i'm using `\include{}` to manage multiple files, and i have to add the local variable to every file there is. Is there a way to fix this in the `.emacs` file? or maybe just in the master file?

Comment: @ArashEsbati, also even with the local variable set, `C-c [` does not prompt options like `\parencite`, `\citeyear` and the like as when using just `biblatex`, neither does it seem to let me find citation entries by searching afterwards. I wonder is it possible to extend the `biblatex` support to `biblatex-chicago`, `biblatex-mla` and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that AUCTeX does not have a style file for `biblatex-chicago`.  You can roll your own one which simply loads `biblatex.el` like this:

```lisp
;;; biblatex-chicago.el --- AUCTeX style for `biblatex-chicago.sty'

(TeX-add-style-hook
 "biblatex-chicago"
 (lambda ()
   (TeX-run-style-hooks "biblatex"))
 LaTeX-dialect)

;;; biblatex-chicago.el ends here
```

Set the variable `TeX-style-private` to a directory of your choice, e.g.:

```lisp
(setq TeX-style-private "~/.emacs.d/mystyles")
```

and save `biblatex-chicago.el` there.

In your `.emacs`, do

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

and restart Emacs and open your file.

The quick and ugly solution would be to fool AUCTeX with something like this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\iffalse
\usepackage{biblatex}
\fi
```

AUCTeX does not parse conditionals, it sees `\usepackage{biblatex}` and loads `biblatex.el` right away.