# How to set up Emacs/AUCTeX/RefTeX to use BibLaTeX by default

Tags: biblatex, emacs, auctex

In previous years I used to rely on good old (tm) BibTeX for my bibliography files.  But nowadays, one should use BibLaTeX with biber as replacement for BibTeX.  Hence, I would love to convince my emacs, to use BibLaTeX as its default.

I read [get emacs to automatically use biber instead of bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129217/get-emacs-to-automatically-use-biber-instead-of-bibtex) and [Customising emacs to use biblatex-biber instead of bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3904/customising-emacs-to-use-biblatex-biber-instead-of-bibtex) but those didn't answer my questions/didn't work for me sufficiently.

For example, I would love to open a new, fresh and empty bibliography file `new.bib`.  In that buffer, Emacs still assumes to use BibTeX, as one can easy check in the menu-bar "Entry-Types".  It presents the classical set of BibTeX entry types.  `@Online` and other new types from BibLaTeX are missing or not presented.

Choosing the "BibTeX dialect" sub menu in the said menu proves, that Emacs still uses BibTeX as dialect.  I would be pleased, if the other option "BibLaTeX" would be chosen automatically instead.

My `.emacs` file contains this:

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber t)
(setq TeX-command-BibTeX "Biber")
```

which seems not to be sufficient enough.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize the variable `bibtex-dialect` to `biblatex`:

> bibtex-dialect is a variable defined in `bibtex.el`.
>   Its value is `BibTeX`
>
> This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
>   satisfies the predicate `symbolp`.
>   You can customize this variable.
>
> Documentation: Current BibTeX dialect.  For allowed values see
>   `bibtex-dialect-list`. To interactively change the dialect use the
>   command `bibtex-set-dialect`.

If you don't like the customize interface, add

```el
(setq bibtex-dialect 'biblatex)
```

to your init file.  The advantage is that customize will not overwrite this variable once `bibtex.el` is loaded.  Hence, you don't need a construct like:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "bibtex"
  (bibtex-set-dialect 'biblatex))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
(bibtex-set-dialect 'biblatex)
```

to your Emacs initialization.

Comment: Thank you @pst, that did the trick!

Comment: Addendum: you should also add `(require 'bibtex)` before `(bibtex-set-dialect 'biblatex)` into your `.emacs` file.